# window.open opens a browser window in different x position on different screen

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, macos-mojave

Here is a very simple script:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

function doit() {
    var features = "top=100,left=0, height=300, width=550";
    console.log(features);
    window.open('', 'test', features);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <button onClick="doit()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load the page in chrome on my main screen and hit the button, the behaviour is exactly what I expected:

[image]

On my external monitor, it becomes

[image]

The new window is opened on the far left side of the screen.

Why? How can I ensure the same behaviour?

Chrome version: 70.0.3538.110